# Assignment to boost::intrusive_ptr without constructor called?

Tags: c++, boost

Is it safe to use assignment to boost::intrusive_ptr this way?

```
class B : public A {...};

boost::intrusive_ptr<A> a = new B;
```

I use an older boost library in this project (1.36) and according the boost documentation I wonder why this compiles, because this assignment should be equivalent to the member function "swap" which seems to need another intrusive ptr but not a raw pointer. Is the constructor of the intrusive_ptr and thus the increment of the counter called at all? (There was a crash (corrupted size vs. prev_size) and stack trace information lead me to this pointer)

At all other places of my software I use:

```
class B : public A {...};

boost::intrusive_ptr<A> a;

a = boost::intrusive_ptr<A>(new B);
```

I thought that some years ago I read that you have to use the second version but I cannot find this text anymore. Or was boost::intrusive_ptr changed in the meantime so that the first example is valid?

Comment: The first code snippet you show has no assignment. `T x = ...;` is an initialization and does not involve `operator=` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of Max I will answer my question in order to close it.
It is save and compiles, because

```
X a = new B;
```

does not invoke the copy operator at all but the copy constructor and even

```
B * p = new B;
boost::intrusive_ptr<A> i;
i = p;
```

would work because there are 3 assignements (which I had overseen)

according to boost doc (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html):

```
 intrusive_ptr & operator=(intrusive_ptr const & r);
 template<class Y> intrusive_ptr & operator=(intrusive_ptr<Y> const & r);
 intrusive_ptr & operator=(T * r);

 // Effects: Equivalent to 
 intrusive_ptr(r).swap(*this)
```